# I want to run Sql Query in script how can i do this

Tags: jquery, sql

Thats What I tried But it give console error. i didnt understand how can run this
 i Have pass jquery variable to sql query but it isnt working

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
            var main = parentTag.parentNode;
            var id = jQuery(main).attr('id')
            var i;
            for (i = id; i<=id; i++) {
                <?php
                $results = $wpdb->get_var("select COUNT(*) from wpq7_pmpro_memberships_users where user_id = $current_user->ID AND membership_id = ?>id <?php");

        if( $results > 0){
            ?>
           if(id == i){
           btn = '<a href="https://thepearledu.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level='+id+'" class="elementor-button-link orange-btn elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">GET IT NOW <font color="#00ff" class="animated infinite flash delay-2s">Only ₹  99.00  </font></span></span></a>'
             jQuery('#'+id).append(btn)
           }
            }
           <?php } ?>
                </script>

            <?php
```

##

i Tried through Ajax  but unfortunatly this is also not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var scriptTag = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
            var parentTag = scriptTag.parentNode;
            var main = parentTag.parentNode;
            var id = jQuery(main).attr('id')

            var i;
            for (i = id; i<=id; i++) {
            jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
            action: 'my_action_name',
            "myData":id
        }}).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);

           if(data == true){
           btn = '<a href="https://thepearledu.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level='+id+'" class="elementor-button-link orange-btn elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">GET IT NOW <font color="#00ff" class="animated infinite flash delay-2s">Only ₹  99.00  </font></span></span></a>'
             jQuery('#'+id).append(btn)
           }
           else{
               btn = '<a href="https://thepearledu.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level='+id+'" class="elementor-button-link orange-btn elementor-button elementor-size-md" role="button"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">GET IT NOW <font color="#00ff" class="animated infinite flash delay-2s">Only ₹  99.00  </font></span></span></a>'
             jQuery('#'+id).append(btn)
           }
        });
            }

                </script>
```

##

in same file function.php

```
function my_action_name(){
     $data = $_POST['myData'];
   $results = $wpdb->get_var("select COUNT(*) from wpq7_pmpro_memberships_users where user_id = $current_user->ID AND membership_id = $data");

        if( $results > 0){
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like this. It won't work. If you need to pass JavaScript variables to PHP you need to send them to the server with an AJAX request. There's some documentation on using AJAX in WordPress here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

Comment: yes i tried through ajax also please check above

Comment: you have not add action  your function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 Promise inside for-each function. So that the loop stop, wait for response from ajax call, than continue loop again with response data.
Promises are a clean way to implement async programming in JavaScript (ES6 new feature). Prior to promises, Callbacks were used to implement async programming. Let's begin by understanding what async programming is and its implementation, using Callbacks.